# I cannot install deb files with the software centre. What are the immediate workarounds?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, 16.04, deb

I need to install .deb files - I've just updated and I need my programmes. However, due to a High priority (yet unassigned) bug, I cannot.

Meta discussion of shipping with bugs aside, how can I install my `.deb` files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention, [this is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573206) which affects lots of people. Add that it affects you on the launchpad page if you wish.

So first - how to install things?

#### Method 1 - alternative GUI

GDebi is a package installer like the software centre, except it only handles DEB files - it's not an app store.

You can install GDebi with the software centre as it is in the repositories, or with `sudo apt-get install gdebi`.

Next, download your DEB file.

Then, to install the package, open GDebi and click File -> Open and navigate to the downloaded DEB file.

[image]

It can take a while to add the open the package - it took around 10 seconds for me.

Then check everything is OK, and click install.

[image]

It will finish, and the program will be installed.

[image]

#### Method 2 - command line

While `apt-get` cannot install from a DEB file, all `apt-get` does is download the file and then call `dpkg`. We can do those tasks ourselves really simply.

First, we download the file.

[image]

Then we open a terminal and navigate to our download location.

[image]

And run the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i FileName.deb
```

replacing FileName with the name of the file.

[image]

Finally, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

[image]

This "fixes" everything - it resolves all dependencies etc.